# ¿ Que hace el operador creador ' Of ' exactamente en Rxjs?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

Entiendo que se usa para emitir una secuencia de valores, según su documentación. En una página vi que es muy similar al operador ' From ', pero no entiendo sus diferencias exactamente. por ejemplo: vi este código tratando de comprender algunas cosas en rxjs:

```js
import { interval, of, from, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { mergeMap, retry } from 'rxjs/operators';

//emit value every 1s
const source = interval(1000);
const example = source.pipe(
  mergeMap(val => {
    //throw error for demonstration
    if (val > 5) {
      return throwError('Error!');
    }
    return of(val);
  }),
  //retry 2 times on error
  retry(2)
);
/*
  output:
  0..1..2..3..4..5..
  0..1..2..3..4..5..
  0..1..2..3..4..5..
  "Error!: Retried 2 times then quit!"
*/
const subscribe = example.subscribe({
  next: val => console.log(val),
  error: val => console.log(`${val}: Retried 2 times then quit!`)
});
```

( también pueden ver su ejecución en: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-jpjcpg?file=index.ts&devtoolsheight=100) )

Sinceramente no entiendo muy bien su funcionamiento. Por ejemplo, intenté cambiar ' Of ' por ' From ' y arroja un error, así que aparte de que no entiendo muy bien por que y para que se usa el operador Of, tampoco entiendo las diferencias entre Of y From. Si alguien es tan amable de explicarme de una manera no muy técnica estaría enormemente agradecido. Gracias de antemano. Saludos!

Answer (score 2):

`of()` toma como parámetro una secuencia de elementos y devuelve un observable que emite cada elemento de la secuencia tal cual como se recibió.

`from()` transforma arreglos, observables, iterables o  promesas a un observable que devuelve sus valores uno a uno.

Si se hace `of([1,2,3],2,'cadena')` el resultado será `[1,2,3],2,cadena`, nótese que el arreglo se emite completo, no elemento por elemento.

Si se hace `from([1,2,3])` el resultado será `1...2...3`, se transforma el  arreglo y se emite cada valor por separado.

> intenté cambiar ' Of ' por ' From ' y arroja un error

Es porque `from()` espera como parámetro un arreglo, observable, promesa o iterable.